# Why EF SaveChanges with no change detection take all cpu and lots of time?

Tags: sql-server, performance, entity-framework

I use Entity Framework 6 schematically like this:

```
MyContext db = new MyContext();
db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
...
//foreach
    db.MyEntityCollection.Add(entity);
    ...
    if (i % 1000 == 0)
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
        db.Dispose();
        db = new MyContext();
        db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    }
```

And the problem is that the instruction SaveChanges takes more than 1.5s for a batch of 1000 items, and 0.250s for 100... 250ms for 100 inserts ! with CPU pikes of 100% (in visual studio) !

Below are the logs of sql server profiler, each insert is aparently done instantly on database side, but there is sometimes about 2-5ms between each insert, I don't really know how to analyse this.

[Screenshot of SQL Server Profile's log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rojN6.png)

May you have solutions to improve the overall processing time, thanks !

Comment: Have you been reading [Optimising bulk inserts with Entity Framework 6](https://www.ben-morris.com/optimising-bulk-inserts-with-entity-framework-6/)? It's round-tripping client->server->client for every row and 1,500ms for 1,000 rows is pretty good, considering. He finishes that article with "Don't use entity framework!" and recommends using SqlBulkCopy instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes it's finally what I've done yersterday, migrate my code to use an entity framework nuget package for bulkinsert. It's 5 times faster now :)